# djanjo get values from related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models-

```
class POWStage(Content):
        time_slot = models.OneToOneField(
                    TaskTime,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    help_text='Link to time slot describing the stage timescale',
                    verbose_name='Time slot link',
                    null=True,
                    blank=True

class TaskTime(Content):
            schedule_finish = models.DateTimeField(
                              help_text='Scheduled finish date',
                              verbose_name='Scheduled finish',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
```

I would like to get the latest end date for a list of POwStages.... e.g. If I have 8 POWStages will have 8 corresponding schedule finish dates.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
pow_stage_list = POWStage.objects.get_stage_by_pow(pow_detail)
            task_time_list = TaskTime.objects.get_task_time_by_id(getattr(pow_stage_list,'time_slot'))
```

and also:

```
 time_list = []
 time_slot=[]
 time_finish[]
 for time_slot in pow_stage_list:
     time_list.append(time_slot)
     for entry in time_list:
          time_entry.append(entry.id)
          for finish_date in time_entry:
               time_finish.append(TaskTime.objects.get_task_time_by_id(finish_date))
```

to try and at least get the values of the finish dates in order to process them further (neither of which are working)

Im thinking of getting the

1. POWStages - using a filter - no problems
   2)FOr each of the POWStages - loop through them to get the id of TaskTime
2. I can do this ok -ish ( I manage to get the id which is returned as
   UUID() object. which I
   cannot then pass to get the TaskTime
3. For each of the TaskTime get the value of schedule finish
4. Iterate through the values to find the latest finish date.

Im thinking there must be a simpler way that I'm missing or at least something that works!!!

Answer (score 0):

2 mins after posting - I managed to work it out:

```
pow_stage_list = POWStage.objects.get_stage_by_pow(pow_detail)
            time_list = TaskTime.objects.filter(powstage__in=pow_stage_list, schedule_finish__isnull=False).latest('schedule_finish')
```

Comment: is there a way to make this more efficient?